# How to show an extra image in Header

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to add an image to my `header.phtml` so I can show my delivery charges next to my logo.

But I keep just getting an broken link image, could osmeon tell me where I am going wrong please? I know the file path is correct because i have used this same path in another place in my website

```
            <a href="/shipping"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('/media/catalog/category/fp-suppliesconsumcat.gif'); ?>" alt=""></a>
```

Comment: I think your Question title differs from your exact question.

Comment: apologise for that it, forget to change it from a question i was going ask and then figured out. Sorry about that

Comment: ok ok and Keyur Shah's answer should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It loos like your are calling media url in `getSKinUrl()` . You have to use this to display image

```
        <a href="/shipping"><img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."/catalog/category/fp-suppliesconsumcat.gif" ?>" alt=""></a>`
```

Let me know if you have any query